# XSLT 1.0 Change output of record based on sibling record parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have an incoming XML file that has a list of participants and dependents that I need to transform slightly so the dependent information is attached as child records to the participant information and the participant record's **EN_PLAN_TYPE** node gets a value based on how many dependents a participant has as well as their relationship.

**INCOMING XML**

```xml
  <EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  </EligibilityRecords>
```

**REQUIREMENTS**

1. Create a new **Dependent_Record** that is a child record of **Eligibility_Detail_Record** for each **DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID** that matches a **PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID**
2. Add an **EN_PLAN_TYPE** field for each Record that has an **EN_PLAN_NAME** of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" that reads:

   - "Ind" if no dependents are found
   - "IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has **DP_RELATIONSHIP** of Spouse
   - "IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has **DP_RELATIONSHIP** of Dependent
   - "Family" if more than one dependent

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Family</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndSpouse</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndChild</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Ind</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
</EligibilityRecords>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="participants" match="Eligibility_Detail_Record" use="PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="Eligibility_Detail_Record[string(PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)]
        [count(.|key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:variable name="participantCount" select="count(key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)[string(DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)])"/>
        <Eligibility_Detail_Record>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(),'PT_')]|EN_PLAN_NAME"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <!--Add an EN_PLAN_TYPE field for each Record that has an EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" that reads:-->
            <xsl:when test="EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Reimbursement Arrangement'">
              <xsl:call-template name="HRA">
                <xsl:with-param name="participantCount" select="$participantCount"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::EN_PLAN_NAME) and starts-with(name(),'EN_')]"/>
          <!--Create a new Dependent_Record that is a child record of Eligibility_Detail_Record for each DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID that matches a PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID-->
          <xsl:for-each select="key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)[string(DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)]">
            <Dependent_Record>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(),'DP_')]"/>
            </Dependent_Record>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="HRA">
    <xsl:param name="participantCount"/>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--"Family" if more than one dependent-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount > 1">Family</xsl:when>
        <!--"IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Dependent-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Dependent'">IndChild</xsl:when>
        <!--"IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Spouse-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Spouse'">IndSpouse</xsl:when>
        <!--"Ind" if no dependents are found-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 0">Ind</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </EN_PLAN_TYPE>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue is that **DP_RELATIONSHIP** is being tested against the first occurrence of each **ELIGIBILITY_DETAIL_RECORD** for a particular participant which will always be blank. I'm just not sure how to easily adjust it to test against the first occurrence of **DP_RELATIONSHIP** for records where a dependent exists (**DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID** is found) and **participantCount** is 1 (I should probably rename the variable to dependentCount but I'll worry about that later)

Comment: Instead of linking to a previous question, please completely describe your current problem here. From your question, it is not clear what the expected and actual output is and there are parts of your code missing. It is very difficult to understand what you're asking if we first need to read and understand the previous question *and* its answer.

Comment: I updated the question to include all pertinent information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than collecting all participants with a key, I'd suggest just collecting the dependents.

Template top level records first then `EN_PLAN_TYPE` and `Dependent_Record` elements using the key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="dependents" match="Eligibility_Detail_Record" use="DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Eligibility_Detail_Record[not(DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template top level records -->
    <xsl:template match="Eligibility_Detail_Record[not(DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(),'PT_')]|EN_PLAN_NAME"/>
            <!--Add an EN_PLAN_TYPE field for each Record that has an EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" -->
            <xsl:if test="EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Reimbursement Arrangement'">
                <xsl:call-template name="HRA"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::EN_PLAN_NAME) and starts-with(name(),'EN_')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('dependents', PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template dependent records -->
    <xsl:template match="Eligibility_Detail_Record[DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID]">
        <Dependent_Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(), 'DP_')]"/>
        </Dependent_Record>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Plan type -->
    <xsl:template name="HRA">
        <xsl:variable name="dependents" select="key('dependents', PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="participantCount" select="count($dependents)"/>
        <EN_PLAN_TYPE>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!--"Family" if more than one dependent-->
                <xsl:when test="$participantCount > 1">Family</xsl:when>
                <!--"IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Dependent-->
                <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and $dependents/DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Dependent'">IndChild</xsl:when>
                <!--"IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Spouse-->
                <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and $dependents/DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Spouse'">IndSpouse</xsl:when>
                <!--"Ind" if no dependents are found-->
                <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 0">Ind</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This answer seems so obvious to me now after seeing it. Staring at a problem for too long can really mess with the thought process. Thanks for the help!